# Changing variable in the wave equation $\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}}=c^{2} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}} $

Tags: wave-equation, change-of-variable

I am trying to implement reverse time migration (RTM). There is a direct wave equation: $$\frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial t^{2}}=c^{2} \frac{\partial^{2} u}{\partial x^{2}}.
$$

I solved it numerically.
Now we need to solve this equation in reverse time. I can't figure out what will happen to the equation after changing the variable: $\,\,\,u(x,t)\,\to\,u(x,-t).$
Please tell me how to change the variable and a possible numerical scheme for solving the equation after changing the variable.

Comment: If $u$ satisfies the wave equation then $v(x,t):=u(x,-t)$ also satisfies the same wave equation: $\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial t^2}=c^2\frac{\partial^2v}{\partial x^2}$ (by the chain rule, because each time applying $\frac{\partial}{\partial t}$ pulls out a minus sign, so doing it twice means you pick up an extra factor of $(-1)^2=1$).